# Given Joint PDF, find such probability and expected value

Tags: probability, density-function

> Let $X$ and $Y$ have the joint pdf $f(x, y) = 6(1 − x − y)$ for $x + y <
> 1, \ 0 < x, \ 0 < y$ and zero elsewhere. Compute $P(2X + 3Y < 1)$ and
>   $E[XY + 2X^2]$.

So I have to find $P(2X + 3Y <1)$:

$$
\int_?^?\int_?^{(1-2y)/3} 6(1-x-y) \ dx \ dy
$$

I know for sure I have made a mistake on domain of $x$ and $y$. I've heard that it's supposed to be 0 to 1/2 and 0 to $(1-2x)/3$ but I have no idea how they got such domain.

And for $$E[XY+2X^2] = \int_?^?\int_?^? 6(1-x-y)  \ dx \ dy
$$

How do I find the domain again and is this the right integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability density function "lives" on the part of the first quadrant that is below the line $x+y=1$. This is a triangle $T$. **Draw** the triangle.  For the expectation question, we want to integrate $(xy +2x^2)(6)(1-x-y)$ over $T$.

Express as an iterated integral. The variable $y$ goes from $0$ to $1-x$, and then $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$.

For the probability that $2X+3Y\lt 1$, **draw** the line $2x+3y=1$. We want to find the probability that $(X,Y)$ lands in the part of $T$ that is below the line $2x+3y=1$. This is a triangle with corners $(0,0)$, $(1/2,0)$, and $(0,1/3)$.

Express as an iterated integral. Note that $y$ goes from $0$ to $(1-2x)/3$ and then $x$ goes from $0$ to $1/2$.

Comment: do you mean last part y goes from 0 to 1/2?

Comment: In the last sentence, $x=0$ to $1/2$ is what I mean. Alternately we can integrate the joint density from $x=0$ to $x=(1-3y)/2$ and then from $y=0$ to $y=1/3$.

Comment: In the post you were integrating first with respect to $x$. In this particular problem, there is no difference in difficulty between the two possible orders.

Comment: understood! thanks

Comment: You are welcome.